# Stacklayout delete on button click

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have outerstacklayout on button click it generates an inner stacklayout.
This inner stacklayout contains element like Label, combobox and a delete_button.
With delete_button I need to delete specific stacklayout.There can be 100 stacklayout and I can delete any number of stacklayout.This is mine code of delete_method

```
private void Delete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stack.Children.Remove(label1); stack.Children.Remove(label2); stack.Children.Remove(label3);
            stack.Children.Remove(label4); stack.Children.Remove(border1);stack.Children.Remove(border2); 
           stack.Children.Remove(border3);      stack.Children.Remove(border4); 
            stack.Children.Remove(button);

            //var button = (SfButton)sender;
            //var parent = button.Parent;
            //OuterStack.Children.Remove(parent);// = (Button)sender;

           // stack.Children.Clear();
           
           // OuterStack.Children.Remove(stack1);
           //OuterStack.Children.Add(stack1);

        }
```

Right now only a single stacklayout is able to delete if I uncomment all stacklayouts get delete.I want to delete specific ones.

Comment: What to do? Can anyone answer this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you create your section, assign a reference to the StackLayout to the Button using the Button's CommandParameter property

```
StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

Button delete = new Button { ... };
delete.CommandParameter = stack;
delete.Clicked = DeleteSection;

stack.Children.Add(delete);
```

in your event handler

```
protected void DeleteSection(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  Button btn = (Button)sender;
  StackLayout stack = (StackLayout)btn.CommandParameter;

  // outer is the StackLayout that contains all sections
  // stack is the inner StackLayout that contains just one section
  outer.Children.Remove(stack);
}
```

here is a [complete example](https://controlc.com/91ad1d5d) that does this (click to see gif)

[image]

Comment: No it is not working ! When I run this suppose I have added 4 stacklayout then it is deleting all the 4 stacklayout. When I am adding new stacklayout then it creates 5 = previous available before delete +1.

Comment: then you are doing something wrong.  This should only delete the StackLayout that contains the button that was pressed.

Comment: **I have done exactly the same as you mentioned but it is deleting all stacklayout's !**

Comment: `stack` in my example refers to the inner StackLayout that surrounds each section, not the outer StackLayout that surrounds ALL of your content.

Comment: ya sir I know that my outer stacklayout name is "outerstacklayout" which I have declared in xaml !

Comment: same, deleting all inner stacklayout !

Comment: you are not creating a new inner stack each time, you are adding ALL of your content to the same stack.  You need to `stack = new StackLayout();` inside of `Load_function` before you add anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the **OuterStack** only contains the multi StackLayouts , you just nned to inviked the following line .

```
protected void DeleteSection(object sender, EventArgs args)
{          
   OuterStack.Children.RemoveAt(2);  // it will remove the third StackLayout in OuterStack
}
```

Comment: no this is not working fine ! It is clearing all the layouts & when I click add stacklayout button it doesnt't show 1 layout but it shows "layouts before deleting + 1 "

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Should I share some code because it is a major project and it contains a lot of dependencies which may take lot of time to resolve !

Comment: You just need to create a sample which contains the issue

Comment: the code in git is incomplete , it seems contains some third party library . You could create a new project and use default control .